# USB communication android

Tags: android, com, usb, host

I'm having still some problems using USBDevice in android communication with USBHost:

following this documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDeviceConnection.html

```
if (device!=null){

        intface = device.getInterface(0);
        endpoint = intface.getEndpoint(0);
        connection = manager.openDevice(device);
        connection.claimInterface(intface, forceClaim);
  if (connection.bulkTransfer(endpoint, buffer, buffer.length, 2000) >= 0) {

                           for(int it = 0; it < bytes.length; it++){                                                                                                                              

                                                sb.append((char) bytes[i]);

                                                   }
```

when i show the lecture, i read some extrange things, like a buffer full of " " or "p" or "a" but nothing related to the message i suppose i receive.

does anyone know where i can find any documentation about this function or any book about  this kind of communication with android?

thanks !!!

Laura.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're reading from or what format the sender is using. Maybe include a little background on the source of the data. Also I would check encodings.

Comment: I assume you've already looked at the ADK guides on Google? http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/adk2.html

Comment: yes, i've cheked that, but i need USB host, not accessory.im usinfg usb for communicate with FTDI devices. thankss

Comment: i think that it could be a problem of BAUDRATE, because the functon CONTROLTRANSFER in the setup, when i select the baudrate that im going to use, 19200 is returning an error